# Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of normed space $X$. Prove that there exists $f \in X^*$ such that $f(Y)=0$ and $\|f\|=1$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of normed space $X$. Prove that there exists $f \in X^*$ such that $f(Y)=0$ and $\|f\|=1$

---

I think Hahn-Banach Theorem must be used. But $f(Y)=0$ and $\|f\|=1$ come from different results of Hahn-Banach Theorem . I have tried to prove it by contradiction. It also doesn't seem working. Could someone help me please?

Comment: I wouldn’t worry about the $\|f\| = 1$ bit. So long as you make $f \neq 0$, you can always divide it by its norm after you construct it. Can you use Hahn-Banach to construct a non-zero $f$ such that $f(Y) = 0$? Also, which variations/corollaries of Hahn-Banach are you familiar with?

Comment: (Also, $Y$ should be a *proper* closed subspace.)

Comment: You should use HB. First take $x_1\notin Y$ and the space $Y_1$ spanned by $Y$ and $x_1.$ The  functional $f_1$ on $Y_1$ given by  $f_1(x_1)=1$ and $f_1\mid_Y=0$ is bounded.  This follows from the fact that the distance from $x_0$ to $Y$ is positive. Then use HB  to extend $f_1$ to a boouded linear functional  $f$ on $X.$ This functional is nonzero. Divide  $f$ by its norm and you are done.

Comment: @Theo Bendit Thank you. I missed the point that $f$ could be divided by its norm.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Can you elaborate more on the functional $f_1$? What should $f_1(x)$ be equal to when $x$ has the form $y + x_1$ with $y \in Y$? Do you have to show that $f_1$ is linear? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\notin Y.$ Denote $d={\rm dist}\, (x,Y).$ As $Y$ is closed we get $d>0.$ Let $Y_1$ denote the subspace spanned by $Y$ and $x.$ Every element of $Y_1$ is uniquely represented as $y+ax,$ where $y\in Y$ and $a\in \mathbb{C}.$ Let $$f_1(y+ax)=ad$$ Then $f_1$ is a linear functional on $Y_1$ vanishing on $Y.$ Moreover for $a\neq 0$ we have $${|f_1(y+ax)|\over \|y+ax\| }={||a|d\over \|y+ax\|}={d\over \|x+a^{-1}y\|}$$ The least upper bound of the last expression is equal $1.$ Hence $\|f_1\|=1.$ By the Hahn-Banach theorem the functional $f_1$ can be extended to a linear functional on $X$ so that $\|f\|=\|f_1\|=1.$